# Mouse move event is not working inside WindowsFormsHost

Tags: c#, wpf, flowlayoutpanel, windowsformshost, onmousemove

I have a button inside WinformHost and I want to move it to any position inside WindowsFormsHost using mouse. I have done like below. But it is flickering when move the mouse over the button. Please help to correct.

```
 <Grid x:Name="myGrid" Background="Transparent" Height="400" Width="700">       
    <WindowsFormsHost Height="200" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  Margin="10,108,0,0" Name="windowsFormsHost1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="200" Background="PaleVioletRed">
        <wf:FlowLayoutPanel Name="FlowPanel" BackColor="Red" Dock="Fill">
            <wf:Panel.Controls> 
                <wf:Button x:Name="Btn1" MouseMove="Btn1_MouseMove" MouseDown="Btn1_MouseDown"  Width="120" Height="120"  Text="BTN1" BackColor="yellow"></wf:Button>
     <wf:Button x:Name="Btn2"  Width="120" Height="120"  Text="BTN2" BackColor="Red"></wf:Button>          
            </wf:Panel.Controls>
        </wf:FlowLayoutPanel>
    </WindowsFormsHost>
</Grid>
private System.Drawing.Point MouseDownLocation;  
private void Btn1_MouseMove(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left)
    {
        btn1.Left = e.X + btn1.Left - MouseDownLocation.X;
        btn1.Top = e.Y + btn1.Top - MouseDownLocation.Y;
    }          
}

private void Btn1_MouseDown(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left)
    {
        MouseDownLocation = e.Location;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you using `wf:FlowLayoutPanel`? That's going to prevent you from positioning the `<wf:Button>` because the `FlowLayoutPanel` is meant to handle positioning for you. Remove the  `<wf:FlowLayoutPanel>` and keep only the `<wf:Button>` and see what happens.

Comment: Because I have to add  few more controls inside same WindowsFormHost

Comment: Then use a `Panel` - or use the `FlowLayoutPanel` for those additional controls but not the `<Button>`. WinForms doesn't require containers to have a single child element unlike WPF.

Comment: My primary aim is to place three buttons inside the windowsformhost. And should be able to move all these three controls to anywhere inside this windowsformhost

Comment: I can move a button when changing xaml as you suggested (a panel and a button inside windowsformhost). But what to do for multiple buttons?

Comment: Then don't use `<FlowLayoutPanel>` at all and position them all manually. Have you read the documentation for what `FlowLayoutPanel` does and how it compares to `Panel`? You can have multiple controls inside a single `Panel` - I don't know why you're asking how to handle multiple buttons when it should be abundantly obvious that you just need to add multiple buttons to a single `Panel` (or even the `Form.Controls` collection directly).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reposting my comment as an answer for the karma:

- WinForms and WPF have very different layout systems: WinForms inherits VB6's "everything is absolutely positioned" concept using only `X`, `Y`, `Width` and `Height`, which is very simple to use, but means that forms need to have a fixed-size or need to be hand-coded to handle resizing events, which is a PITA to implement.

  - WinForms did add the `Anchor` and `Dock` properties for very basic layouts.
  - In the .NET Framework 2.0, WinForms added `FlowLayoutPanel` and `TableLayoutPanel` which helped as well.
  - `FlowLayoutPanel` and `TableLayoutPanel` handle the absolute positioning of elements for you, which means you cannot directly set a control's coordinates (or rather, setting coordinates just positions the control relative to its containing panel or cell).
- WPF, however, uses a very different layout system which does not use absolute positioning at all (you can only set coordinates inside a WPF `<Canvas>` element), instead it has a good assortment of built-in layout-controls such as `StackPanel`, `DockPanel`, `WrapPanel`, and more - which is far more flexible than WinForm's *aneamic* layout controls.

  - WPF and XAML were designed to support both application UIs and "documents" (remember Microsoft's ill-fated PDF competitor "XPS"? That was based on XAML's layout model) - which is why it's far more flexible than WinForms' model.
  - However, WPF has major programmer-ergonomics issues, such as being designed to only allow a single child control per `Panel` cell (the idea being that you should use another `<Panel>` as the child of the layout-control and then add children to that - but it's very counter-intuitive at first after being used to WinForm's ubiquitous `ControlsCollection`).
- So my point is that WPF and WinForms have fundamentally different layout models, so don't use WPF techniques with WinForms, and vice-versa - which is why WinForms' `FlowLayoutPanel` doesn't work the way you think it does - if you think it works anything like WPF's `WrapPanel`.
- Because WinForm's `FlowLayoutPanel` "takes control" over the position and size of its child controls, it means that setting `Left` and `Top` (and possibly `Width` and `Height` depending on the `Dock` and `Anchor` settings) on each child control is futile because they'll be overridden by the `FlowLayoutPanel`.
- So if you want to set the positions of WinForms controls absolutely, then don't use `FlowLayoutPanel` at all, just add the Controls directly to the parent's `ControlsCollection` and then set coordinates and size.
- The `WindowsFormsHost` is a WPF control, not a WinForms control, so it can only have a single WinForms control as its content (the `.Child` property). Use a WinForms `Panel` control to have a simple collection of WinForms controls that have their position and size set manually.

Like so:

```
<Grid
    x:Name="myGrid"
    Background="Transparent"
    Height="400"
    Width="700"
>
    <WindowsFormsHost
        Height="200"
        HorizontalAlignment="Left"
        Margin="10,108,0,0"
        Name="windowsFormsHost1"
        VerticalAlignment="Top"
        Width="200"
        Background="PaleVioletRed"
    >
        <wf:Panel
            Name="FlowPanel"
            BackColor="Red"
            Dock="Fill"
        >
            <wf:Panel.Controls> 

                <wf:Button
                    x:Name="Btn1"
                    MouseMove="Btn1_MouseMove"
                    MouseDown="Btn1_MouseDown"
                    Width="120"
                    Height="120"
                    Text="BTN1"
                    BackColor="yellow"
                />

                <wf:Button
                    x:Name="Btn2"
                    Width="120"
                    Height="120"
                    Text="BTN2"
                    BackColor="Red
                />

            </wf:Panel.Controls>
        </wf:Panel>
    </WindowsFormsHost>
</Grid>
```